# I need my mobile menu items to close on click

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, menu, onclick

I have a mobile menu that after I click the icon to open it and I click a menu item the menu doesn't go away. I have a one page site so it just covers everything. This is the script I have. Should I add anything?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776;</div>');

$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").toggle();
    $("#nav").addClass("dropdown")();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share any of the code that adds the menu items? I'd need to see what the DOM should look like and what elements are being clicked on. It's likely the click event is being captured by the menu item, not the menu itself.

Comment: what does `.dropdown` css look like?  Also, you have syntax error in `.addClass("dropdown")();`, you should remove the `()` from it at the end.

Comment: This is the html that gets created from the script 
'<div id="mobile-menu">
<div id="menu">☰</div>
<ul id="nav" class="js">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>' I am not sure if this will help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can safely get rid of this code:  `$("#nav").addClass("dropdown")();` unless there are CSS rules applied to `.dropdown`, and we should see them, so we can help you better in that case, but if not than just place in the CSS for #nav:

```
#nav { display: none; }
```

This will cause it to be initially hidden, and `.toggle` should toggle the display state automatically, each time it gets clicked.

Also, what is the reason you are adding `<div id="menu">&#9776;</div>` using jQuery, instead of in the actual HTML of the page?  I would, personally, just add it in within the HTML `body` tag of the page, since it doesn't seem like it is code-worthy to me.  Just put it in HTML before the element with an `id="nav"`

Comment: I removed the '$("#nav").addClass("dropdown")();' from the script and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try, just the following than:  `$("#nav").toggleClass("dropdown");` within the click event without `.toggle`.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: I am honestly not great at script so I tried adding that in but it didn't work